# JSONException: Value <br cannot be converted into JSONobject

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm making a simple login page using xampp server with MySQL database. I keep getting the error above and unfortunately, cant find the right answer. I'm using my real android phone instead of the emulator. The log box doesn't seem to display any type of error so i'm not sure as to what went wrong. Thanks in advance

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.43.231/Login/login.php";
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String usernameS = username.getText().toString().trim();
            final String passwordS = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if (usernameS.isEmpty() || passwordS.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Enter Valid Username & Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                    boolean responseStatus = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
                                    if (responseStatus) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put(KEY_USERNAME, usernameS);
                        params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, passwordS);

                        return params;
                    }
                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue =Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","blast");

$username=$_POST['username']);
$password=$_POST['password']);

$sql=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * from blast_user where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,"sss",$username,$password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql,$username,$password);

$response=array();
$response["success"]=true;

echo json_encode($response);
>?
```

Comment: Have you checked on what the raw response is from your php script? I'm guessing there are some php warnings or notices in the output, thus tainting what should be pure json.

Comment: "JSONException: Value <br cannot be converted into JSONobject" Notice the `<br` looks like your PHP code is generating html output (might be a notice).. And what it this `>?` in de PHP code should be `?>`

Comment: If this is your actual php code, you have parse errors at `$username=$_POST['username']);` (extra end parens).

Comment: You are trying to use prepared statements, but have not supplied any placeholders to bind too. Your SQL should be `SELECT * from blast_user where username = ? and password = ?` ... subsequently you only need two `s` in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,"ss",$username,$password);`

Answer (score 0):

Do this -

```
$username=$_POST['usernameS']);
$password=$_POST['passwordS']);
```

instead of -

```
$username=$_POST['username']);
$password=$_POST['password']);
```